# Parse.com | Trying to get a list of subscribed channels leading to app crash

Tags: java, android, xml, parse-platform

To show the user a list of his channels I did this:

```
package za.hseldo.client;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.ParseInstallation;

 public class Aansteekbord extends Activity {

Object[] myChannels;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aansteekbord);

    myChannels = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getList("channels").toArray();
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutA);

    for (int i = 0; i < myChannels.length - 1; i++) {
        TextView tempView = new TextView(getBaseContext());
        tempView.setText(myChannels[i].toString());
        layout.addView(tempView);
    }
}
}
```

I get an error at line 18. This is only an example, I have found the same in other areas, that the ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getList("channels") doesn't work. The documentation provides that code?

Comment: Have you checked that that myChannels is actually being set. If it is not then when you try to call myChannels.length it will cause an error because you can't call a member variable of a null object

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the objectId first then you can get the list:

```
ParseInstallation.getQuery().get(objectId).getList("channels")
```

If you need to get the object id:

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getObjectId();
```

The code is from the documentation under parse installation: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/

Hope this helps!